# How to in Scala handle NoSuchElementException without throwing exception

Tags: scala, exception

I'm using Play framework by Scala. I have Postgresql database. It fetches data by following code:-

```
def eventById(id: Long): Option[EventRow] = {
    val action = events.filter(_.id === id)
    val results = db.run(action.result.head)
    val notFound = None: Option[EventRow]
      try {
        Some(Await.result(results, Duration.Inf))
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => Logger.info(s"Failed to fetch event by id: $e.")
          notFound
      } finally {
      }
  }
}
```

Here in case data not bound it throws exception. Here I don't want to throw exception.I want to return notFound. I cannot even compile without throwing Exception.

Is there a way to return notFound if event not found in database?

Please let me know? Thanks!

Comment: Just use `headOption` instead of `head` and then check if it's some or none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
def eventById(id: Long): Option[EventRow] = {
  val action = events.filter(_.id === id)
  val res: Future[Option[EventRow]] = db.run(action.result.headOption)
  Await.result(res, Duration.Inf)
}
```